# How to find what form is calling a public procedure

Tags: delphi, procedure, vcl, self

I have too many Forms and I have a procedure that should be running on all form when created

```
procedure TDM.SetupForm(Max, DisableResize,
DisableMove: Boolean; FormWidth: Integer = 0; FormHeight: Integer = 0);
var
Form: TForm;
begin
Form := ??? // How to find the what form is running this procedure?
  Form.AutoScroll := True;
  if Max then
  begin
    Form.Width := Screen.WorkAreaWidth;
    Form.Height := Screen.WorkAreaHeight;
    Form.Top := 0;
    Form.Left := 0;
  end
  else
  begin
    if FormWidth > 0 then
      Form.Width := FormWidth;
    if FormHeight > 0 then
      Form.Height := FormHeight;
    Form.Position := poScreenCenter;
    Form.Align := alCustom;
  end;
  if DisableResize then
    DeleteMenu(GetSystemMenu(Form.Handle, False), SC_SIZE, MF_BYCOMMAND);
  if DisableMove then
    DeleteMenu(GetSystemMenu(Form.Handle, False), SC_MOVE, MF_BYCOMMAND);

  Form.BorderIcons := [biSystemMenu];
  if Form.Height > Screen.WorkAreaHeight then
    Form.Height := Screen.WorkAreaHeight;
  if Form.Width > Screen.WorkAreaWidth then
    Form.Width := Screen.WorkAreaWidth;

  Form.ShowHint := True;
  Form.OnClose := CloseFormAction;
end;
```

I call this `Procedure` on `FormCreate` event
How can I find what form is calling this `procedure` and use it inside same procedure **without passing it as parameter?**

Answer (score 2):

> I call this procedure on `FormCreate` event

It seems to me you don't actually need to know the "Last Created Form", but rather which form is currently being created, which you want to call this code for. If that is the case, simply add a `TForm` parameter to this procedure instead of declaring a variable and trying to obtain it from elsewhere...

```
procedure TDM.SetupForm(Form: TForm; Max, DisableResize,
  DisableMove: Boolean; FormWidth: Integer = 0; FormHeight: Integer = 0);
begin
  ...Use the `Form` parameter...
```

Then you would pass `Self` into this whenever you call it from `FormCreate`...

```
DM.SetupForm(Self, ....
```

---

Ultimately, this sort of thing is best accomplished by creating a base form first, and then inheriting all the rest of your forms from this base. Such code would be implemented in the base form's constructor, and then you wouldn't have to explicitly call it from each and every form you wish to apply it to. However, it seems you already have many forms written and this would require modifying all of your existing code to consider the base form. Such design should be done from the beginning of development.

---

I must also note that putting UI code of such nature into a data module is not the right practice. A data module's purpose is to be disconnected from the UI. That's why it's not actually a visible form, but a non-visual-component-only solution. It's best to put such code in independent units for that purpose, such as `MyApp.UICommon.pas`.

Comment: I already used this method but it's not what I really want, this is just a part of my procedure there will be to many parameters to pass, and it's really confusing me and others team members, I want to pass only changed parameters that's not equal to all forms, one more question what is the risk of putting UI code into data module? thank you

Comment: @SaRaFinBas: The problem with putting UI code in a datamodule is that **it's a data module**. It's supposed to contain only code and components related to data and non-UI functionality. It's not part of the UI - it's a data module.

Comment: @SaRaFinBas Your coding habits remind me of someone who would rather cut the floor out of their car and pedal their feet on the ground to power their car, rather than getting the engine running.

Comment: Did i said it's not a data module? You guys keep telling me it's a data module, I know its a data module and its suppose to contains non-visual component but if i put all non-visual component on Main Form there is no problem at all and it will not effect the application at all, so if I use data module to keep all my procedures, functions and public variables in one place, what is wrong with it? except the data module purpose.